# (ODRpack) Getting the sum of square orthogonal distance between a point cloud and a curve

Tags: python, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I am trying to fit a curve to a point cloud. I want to examine the orthogonal distance of the fit under different parameters. I am using ODRpack from scipy.odr. I know the ODRpack gives a good geometric fit but my main purpose is to get the distance rather than doing the regression. Hence, I set the initial guess (`beta0`) to be the parameter i wanted to examine and set the `maxit` to be 0, hoping it will give the orthogonal distance between the curve and the point cloud but it does not. As i have checked, the `sum_square_delta` is zero for all point, and it does not make sense as i am not fitting a horizontal line.

How do i fix it so that i can get the orthogonal distance? Solutions not using ODRpack is also welcome.